Is anyones Nextjs application breaking because of useReducer?
I have a fully functioning Nextjs 14 applciation that semantically works. Its of a website I made that's already deployed with no issues. But now when I'm running the project again in VScode, it breaks giving a useReducer error.
Error Screenshot
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useReducer')

So far I haven't found any useful documentation that directly addresses this issue. I've attached my dependances and error that I'm receiving.
Dependancy List
"dependencies": {
    "@vercel/analytics": "^1.1.1",
    "@vercel/speed-insights": "^1.0.1",
    "next": "^14.0.4",
    "package": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "17.0.25",
    "@types/react": "18.0.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "daisyui": "^4.4.19",
    "eslint": "8.14.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.2",
    "typescript": "4.6.3"
  }

I've ran my project normally with sudo npm run dev, expecting my site to come up. Unfortunately I've seen the same error in my other pojects. The same useReducer error I got also appeared in a brand new Nextjs 14 project that was installed with create-next-app <project-name>.
After seeing the error, I've updated and upgraded all of my dependanies with sudo npm update && upgrade. This means making everything up-to-date with the maintained repos or libraries that aren't bug ridden. It did not work as wel.
Then I deleted the .next and node_modules folder in my project correctly. I'm working on an M1, which means going through permissions every single turn ensuring security. This went well, but was not the solution.

From the looks of it you are using the 'useReducer' hook somewhere in your application and are trying to access one of its properties.
For example if you have the following code:
const myObject = {}
console.log(myObject.someProperty) //you get undefined

something similar is happening with your useReducer hook. A part of your code is trying to access it and is throwing an error because the property that it is trying to access does not exist.
Try searching in vscode for all the instances where you use 'useReducer' and make sure the property that your code is trying to access exists.
useRedcuer documentation: https://react.dev/reference/react/useReducer

At first, I had doubts because I do not recall ever using that hook in my project. And I was right. I checked every file in my current project and its not there. It also doesn't make sense to have to search for the useReducer() because I'm getting the same problem in a new project as I've clearly stated in my problem above.

That's weird, can you share the code of the page that is causing this issue? Personally I have never experienced this. Another thing that comes to mind is maybe to try downgrading the Next.Js version and see if that fixes the issue.

I could show my project, but the thing is that its affecting all pages on my site. But I'll downgrade for sure.

Please let me know if that helps. I just started a brand new project and have not experienced that issue so far.
command: npx create-next-app@latest my-app --typescript --tailwind --eslint
package-lock.json:
"next": "14.2.3",
"react": "^18",
"react-dom": "^18"

Hi there, bad news. It doesn't work. I've downgraded Nextjs and nothing worked. I then found the node was old to I upgraded that further. it didn't work. The arguments you added in your create-next-app command is the same as mine now. But the error still persists.

When I create a new next app, that breaks too with the same error. Possibly a version of react is breaking with this version of next
